# Mongodb injection with find arrays?

Tags: php, mongodb

What kind of situations do I have to look out for with this type of of querying?

```
$collection->find(array('key' => $user_string_value))
```

I won't be using the `$where` syntax at all with user input as it seems blatantly insecure without lots of injection prevention.

Is the above find call 100% secure regardless of what is in that variable?

Comment: Are you enforcing its type?

Comment: I'm not type casting at all. Should I be type casting variables to strings if I want them to be strings? What about date objects?